# Salesforce PHP REST Client

Tags: php, rest, salesforce

I'm trying to utilise Salesforce connected app to push data from my application to Salesforce CRM.

Backend from where i plan to push data is PHP based.

From Salesforce developer website only resources available for PHP to star with are SOAP client which seems to be pretty outdated [PHP Toolkit](https://developer.salesforce.com/page/PHP_Toolkit)
and REST example using CURL and OAuth [REST OAuth PHP](https://developer.secure.force.com/cookbook/recipe/interact-with-the-forcecom-rest-api-from-php)

Does anyone know if there is any official PHP Client library to operate with Salesforce Accounts/Contacts/Events etc, or i will end up writing my own REST wrapper.

Thanks!

Comment: This https://github.com/salesforce-marketingcloud/FuelSDK-PHP ?

Comment: @ficuscr indeed interesting. I havent run across this one. But this one still uses SOAP, not SF REST API endpoints. I was more into using their REST endpoints, with a bit higher abstraction from SF implementation.

Answer (score -1):

You can give a shot to https://github.com/goetas-webservices/salesforce-enterprise-client

It is a pure PHP SOAP client with IDE type hinting support and PSR-7 compatible.